# Unable to understand mouse event syntax in Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseevent, mouseover, mouselistener

I am trying to understand following D3 code to implement zoom feature in my D3 chart. https://gist.github.com/jasondavies/3689931

In the code, there're these lines:

```
.on("mousemove.zoomRect", function() {    // line 90

.on("mouseup.zoomRect", function() {    // line 99
```

I am not aware of this syntax. I tried the docs but not sure what to look for. `zoomRect` is a boolean variable, what does it mean when we say `mousemove.zoomRect ?`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [.on](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Internals#dispatch_on):

> If an event listener was already registered for the same type, the
>   existing listener is removed before the new listener is added. To
>   register multiple listeners for the same event type, the type may be
>   followed by an optional namespace, such as "click.foo" and
>   "click.bar". Likewise, you can remove all registered listeners for a
>   given namespace by saying dispatch.on(".foo", null).

The `.zoomRect` is a namespace.  I believe he is using for saftey he's setting events on the global window object.

Comment: I understand it now. Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: Just to clear that up, `.zoomRect` in the event listener has nothing to do with the boolean variable, right?